# Why Map.make.fold more like List.fold_right (which is non-tail-recursive)?

Tags: dictionary, ocaml, tail-recursion, fold

Question naive on Ocaml's fold: Could you explain why Map.make.fold is designed more like List.fold_right instead of List.fold_left, noting that List. fold_right is not tail_recursive? There should have been Map.make.fold_left and Map.make.fold_right ?

```
type of Map.make.fold 
val fold : (key -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b -> 'b

type of List.fold_left    
val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a

type of List.fold_right
val fold_right : ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.S.html#VALfold) of what Map's fold *does*: `(f kN dN ... (f k1 d1 a)...)`, you'll see that it actually performs a left fold (where left is the smallest key and right is the biggest key).

For a Map or Set, which is a binary search tree, it is pretty easy to traverse it in both directions, unlike a (singly-linked) list, which can only be traversed in one direction; so it's equally easy to make tail-recursive folds in both directions.

As for the order of the arguments, I guess it's just a design decision. Haskell's list folds (`foldl` and `foldr`) as well as [Haskell's Map's `fold`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers-0.4.0.0/Data-Map.html#v:fold) consistently have the initial value argument before the list argument. I think the consistency is good. OCaml's list folds from different directions have different argument orders (I guess it might be because for a left fold, you put the initial argument on the left and progressive "fold" it to the right over the list; whereas for right fold, you put the initial element on the right and progressively fold it left over the list; so the placement of the arguments agrees with the action visually.) Apparently OCaml's Map's fold's argument order is the same as its right fold. I don't think it really matters.

As for having two Map folds, there might be some value to that. Haskell's Map introduced both direction of folding in GHC 6.12. Previously, there was only a right fold. Most uses of fold on a Map probably doesn't care about the order though.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies that the order of arguments in a function is related to whether it is tail recursive, but that is not true. `List.fold_right` could just as well have had the same signature as `List.fold_right`, but that would not change its implementation.